# next.js css error: Selector "[class$="-colorTextSecondary"]" is not pure (pure selectors must contain at least one local class or id)

Tags: css, next.js13

The following is in my CSS modules (`post.module.css`):

```
.summaryTypography{
    margin: 10px 20px 0 20px;
    text-align:right !important;
    
    [class$="-colorTextSecondary"]{
        text-align:justify;
    }
}
```

It worked perfect in react.js, I used `class$` to assign individual styles to inner components of a main component. However when I try to same in next.js I get the following error:

[image]

From my research, I put this CSS summary class in globals.css and the error disappeared. However it really belongs in `post.module.css`. How could I alter and keep this same class in the `post.module.css` file?

Comment: Similar issue here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72293500/selector-root-is-not-pure-pure-selectors-must-contain-at-least-one-local-cla

Comment: @ralph.m I'm seeing that it's recommending putting those classes in the global.css file. I tried the initial hack solution but it didnt work giving error: `isProd is not defined`. But `class$="-colorTextSecondary"` is really a className within the `.summaryTypography` component so I don't understand why it should be a global component. It's just being used in 1 place, not globally